# Fedora 14 system-config-firewall-tui gone?

Tags: iptables, fedora-14

On Fedora I used to be abble to configure custom ports into the Firewall by going to setup and following the required steps till I got to something like this:

[image]

Well that menu is here no more. I can only allow "trusted services" into the Firewall.

I can change them by hand editing:

`/etc/sysconfig/iptables`

And I can test them using:

`netstat -tulpn | less`

The thing is I really liked the old interface. Allowed me to ssh to the machine and, in my opinion was less prone to errors.

**Has it been discontinued? Am I missing some module?**

Answer (score 0):

Look into system-config-securitylevel-tui. The "customize" button is what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks for your answer. On Fedora 14 the "customize" button only shows "Trusted Services" and doesn't let me add ports in a manual fashion...

Comment: That's not good, I haven't used the tui in ages, I just stick everything in /etc/sysconfig/iptables too. We need finer control of our firewall rules, so it hasn't come up for me. Good luck finding what you need!

Comment: thks, hope someone reads this and knows more!